# How to include meta in the "imBack" card action?

Tags: c#, botframework

```
new CardAction
{
    Type = "imBack",
    Title = "Undo?",
    Value = $"I want to undo last action <meta productId=\"{product.Id}\"/>"
}
```

I'm trying to include the meta tag in the `CardAction` with `ActionTypes = "imBack"`.

The bot display the button in the card nicely (the meta tag is hidden), but when the message is sent to the user, the meta tag still displayed in the chat box.

What should I do?

Thanks,

Comment: What channel are you using?

Comment: @Lars: I'm using skype desktop, skype (Android), skype (iOS)

Comment: The double quotes inside the string might be causing the issue.  Try a single quote

Comment: @kienct89 Any luck with this? Appreciate if you shared with me how you did it?

Answer (score 0):

Please can you try single quotes around {product.id} or using  
" to escape. That might be your issue.